# Pig script to get top 3 data in a single record

Tags: apache-pig

I have the sample data as

`user_id, date, accessed url, session time`
the data refers to the top 3 interests of the user depending on the session time.

Got the data using the code:

```
top3 =  FOREACH DataSet{
    sorted = ORDER DataSet BY sessiontime DESC;
    lim    = LIMIT sorted 3;
    GENERATE flatten(group), flatten(lim);
};
```

---

Output:

```
    (1,20,url1,2484)
    (1,20,url2,1863)
    (1,20,url3,1242)
    (2,22,url4,484)
    (2,22,url5,63)
    (2,22,url6,42)
    (3,25,url7,500)
    (3,25,url8,350)
    (3,25,url9,242)
```

But I want my output to be like this:

```
(1,20,url1,url2,url3)
(2,22,url4,url5,url6)
(3,25,url7,url8,url9)
```

Please help.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input, as well as the code that you used to group the sets. Without that it is difficult to tell what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  The problem is that you `FLATTEN` the bag of URLs when you really want to keep them all in one record.  So do this instead:

```
top3 =  FOREACH DataSet{
    sorted = ORDER DataSet BY sessiontime DESC;
    lim    = LIMIT sorted 3;
    GENERATE flatten(group), lim.url;
};
```

Based on the output you got, you will now get

```
(1,20,{(url1),(url2),(url3)})
(2,22,{(url4),(url5),(url6)})
(3,25,{(url7),(url8),(url9)})
```

Note that the URLs are contained inside a bag.  If you want to have them as three top-level fields, you will need to use a UDF to convert a bag into a tuple, and then `FLATTEN` that.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding the UDF?

Comment: See, for example -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544602/how-to-flatten-a-group-into-a-single-tuple-in-pig/18548696#18548696

Comment: is there any UDF in java for this?

Comment: See the answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057223/using-pig-how-do-i-parse-a-mixed-format-line-into-tuples-and-a-bag-of-tuples/19058408#19058408